# How can I make the menu folding/unfolding function? (double layer)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a menu folding/unfolding function.
When there is one submenu, it is completed, but the problem is when there are two submenus.
When you unclick a menu with the expand function, all of the expanded submenus are not closed, but only the first submenus are closed.

When I unclick a menu with the expand function, how do I close all of the expanded submenus?

Thank you. This is my code.

**"The BiG One" is the main menu with onclick event. 

"First SubMenu" is the first submenu, "Second SubMenu" is the second submenu. 

If I click the "The BiG One", the "First SubMenu" should be opened,
and If I click the "First SubMenu", the "Second SubMenu" should be opened. 

And If I click again "The BiG One", "First SubMenu", "Second SubMenu" should be unfolded together.**

- HTML

```
  <tr >
            <td style="background-color:white;" onclick={schedulingClick}>
                <div class="interval-same">
                    <span>The BiG One</span>
                    <span>&#9660;</span>
                </div>
            </td>        
            <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
                    <td key={record.id}>
                        {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
                    </td>
            </template>
        </tr>   

  
        <tr >  
            <td style="background-color:#FFF2CC" if:true={schedulingPeople} onclick={beforeNoonClick}>
                <div class="interval-same">
                    <span>ㄴFirst SubMenu</span>
                    <span>&#9660;</span>
                </div></td>
            <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
                                    <td key={record.id} if:true={schedulingPeople} style="background-color:#FFF2CC">
                                        {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
                                    </td>
            </template>
        </tr>

    <tr > 
        <td style="background-color:#FFF2CC" if:true={beforeNoonDetails}>
         ㄴㄴSecond SubMenu</td>
        <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
                                <td key={record.id} if:true={beforeNoonDetails} style="background-color:#FFF2CC">
                                    {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
                                </td>
        </template>
    </tr>
    <tr > 
        <td style="background-color:#FFF2CC" if:true={beforeNoonDetails}>
         ㄴㄴSecond SubMenu</td>
        <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
                                <td key={record.id} if:true={beforeNoonDetails} style="background-color:#FFF2CC">
                                    {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
                                </td>
        </template>
    </tr>
```

- JS

```
    schedulingPeople = false;
    beforeNoonDetails = false;

    schedulingClick(){
        this.schedulingPeople = !this.schedulingPeople;
    }
   

    beforeNoonClick(){
        this.beforeNoonDetails = !this.beforeNoonDetails;
    };
```